# Android edit text showing weird text

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to android. I just created a simple application using Aynctask. Basically, it uses Asynctask to iterate through a loop and show the iteration number in the text box. I created both a edittext and a textview and bot shows some weird text. I try creating a toast, and the toast shows the same text correctly. Here is the source code:

```
package com.jeannius.me;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    int[] color1 = {0xFFe48701, 0xFFa5bc4e, 0xFF1b95d9, 0xFFcaca9e, 0xFF6693b0, 0xFFf05e27, 0xFF86d1e4,
            0xFFe4f9a0, 0xFFffd512, 0xFF75b000, 0xFF0662b0, 0xFFede8c6, 0xFFcc3300, 0xFFd1dfe7,
            0xFF52d4ca, 0xFFc5e05d, 0xFFe7c174, 0xFFfff797, 0xFFc5f68f, 0xFFbdf1e6, 0xFF9e987d,
            0xFFeb988d, 0xFF91c9e5, 0xFF93dc4a, 0xFFffb900, 0xFF9ebbcd, 0xFF009797, 0xFF0db2c2};

    TextView yyr;
    EditText ud;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
         yyr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);
         ud = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);




        Button myb =(Button)findViewById(R.id.mybut);
        yyr.setTextColor(0xFFE48701);
        ud.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);

        myb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {

                new mySyncTask().execute();             
            }

        });      

   }

    class mySyncTask extends AsyncTask< Void, Integer, Void>{

        String red;     

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

            for(Integer j=0; j<5; j++){             
              red = String.valueOf(j);                  
                publishProgress(j);             
            SystemClock.sleep(3000);}           
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), red.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

            yyr.setText(String.valueOf(values));
            ud.setText(values.toString(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), red.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }       

    }  

}
```

Comment: in the toast you show red, in the text views you show values, why is that?

Comment: What exactly is the "weird" text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

values is an array.  Use it like this: `String.valueOf( values[0] )`